# How do I make a svg icon and a select input box vertically align in a div?

Tags: css

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jj9gLxta/1/

```
#wrapper {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-table;
}
#wrapper select {
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

I'd like to make the svg icon and select box vertically aligned.

BTW the svg icon and the select input may be in other sizes, so I need some css to make it applicable to different designs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use something like

```
display: table;
```

and also:

```
display: table-cell;
```

Like the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/aq8gv4hj/1/

Better explained here: 
https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: oh, the original size works for me... this's so weird.

Comment: Hi Matei, if your still having issues it seems to work if you put the select inside a div and use display: table-cell also.  

http://jsfiddle.net/fx2czcj3/1/

Answer (score 2):

This [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kmg3j2zk/) should have the desired effect. I removed styling from the `wrapper` element, and made these changes:

```
#wrapper select {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
}
#icon {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: this is not perfect as the previous answer with the `table` method. but that resolution has something wrong with a bigger icon...